# do the iPhone and iPad simulators share the same Documents folder?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm developing for 6.1 iOS and my app is writing some files to the Documents folder.

When I look at the path to the Documents folder in the debugger, it looks like it is the same folder for both the iPhone and the iPad simulator.

Is that right?   I expected each simulator to have its own Documents folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is right. The path for the documents folder is same.

Comment: Thanks.   That sorts that.  :-)

Comment: I'd to add a link to an app that helps with using the Simulator: http://simpholders.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Both simulators share common Documents folder (if both are similar version).

But if they are different versions (Example: iOS 5 iPhone simulator and iOS 6 iPad simulator) then both have two different Documents folder.

Answer (score 1):

Path for ipad/iphone is same.
its only change according to ios version like supposed you have run your code for ipad on ios 5 simulator and same code run for iphone on ios 6 simulator than both have different path.

Answer (score 0):

yes, they use the same document folder.

In simulator folder is created according the iOS version.